# How to add admin user attributes in Magento

Tags: magento, addattribute

I'd like to add some new attributes to the admin users in Magento. These users are different than customers (just to make it clear) and it's only possible to set their user/name/lastname/mail/pass, but I'd like to add a few new attributes.

To do so, I guess I can use the addattribute function, but I need to find out which is the id of these admin users. For example, if I want to add a new attribute to a customer, I can use a function like this:

```
$setup->addAttribute('customer','attribute_id', $attr );
```

So, in this case, 'customer' is the id for customers. How can I find out which id is used for admin users? (this question can be extended to "How can I find the different id for the different types of attributes in Magento?").

==There is a chance that there is no way to change this. I've taken a look at the admin_user table and it's quite simple, all fields are there. So maybe there are no attributes in this case.==

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can find all such ids (entity ids) in the `eav_entity_type` table. 
And yes, there is no record for admin user. Because all data about admin users are stored in flat tables but not in eav. So to add a new attribute to admin user, you need to add a new column in the `admin_user` table

Comment: Thanks for your answer, vsushkov. But adding this new column manually means to modify the admins module as well, isn't it? I guess it won't be enough adding it only on the template... we should also modify the save function?

Comment: No, you don't need to modify any code. After you add a new column (f.e. karma_points), you can do something like that: `Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load(1)->setKarmaPoints(500)->save();` and the corresponded cell will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a column to the `admin_user` table.

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'), 'location', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length' => 256,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null
));
```

Then, if you want to add/edit this field from the backend you need to rewrite the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main::_prepareForm` and add a new element in there:

```
        $fieldset->addField('location', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'is_active',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('location'),
            'id'        => 'is_active',
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('location'),
            'class'     => 'input-select',
            'style'     => 'width: 80px',
            'options'   => array('1' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes'), '0' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No')),
        ));
```

Clear the cache and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

No option till 1.7

thats what i use in the template to show the sku to an specific user bit dirty but works fine:

```
<?php
  //EGS SKU added for Power User
  $_powerUser = 777;
  if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId() == $_powerUser) 
  {
   echo '<div class="price-from">' . $_product->getSku() . '</div>';
  }
?>
```